# Underline css3 transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, underline

How do I create an *underline animation* from left to right on `hover` in CSS3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This was a really tricky question.

The only solution I can come up with is to transition a `border-bottom` on `:hover` or I should actually say that I'm transitioning `border-bottom`, `width` and `margin-right` to make the `border-bottom` appear and at the same time keep, in this case, the links aligned.

Hard to explain, so I made a quick example which isn't perfect and looks a bit messy, but at least it shows how I mean. :-)

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/46a8u/)

HTML

```
<a href="#">Link</a><a href="#">Link</a>
```

CSS

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;    
    margin-right: 39px; 
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Setting the width to 0 and thereby have the actual content flow out of the links could have side effects on the rest of the layout. I’d suggest using a generated element (:after) instead, position it absolute at the bottom of the link, and than animate the width of that pseudo element instead.