# Make underline shoot under link on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I am looking for a way to make an underline shoot across underneath a link when hovered and go away again when the mouse in not hovering. I'm not sure if I'm doing a good job explaining, so please tell me if you don't understand. I'm pretty sure that this cannot be done with an actual underline, maybe with an `<hr>` tag? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://www.net-kit.com/10-ways-to-animate-your-links/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;    
    margin-right: 39px; 
    width: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
}

a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
            transition: 0.5s ease;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 9px;
}
```

Taken from here: [Underline css3 transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489203/underline-css3-transition)

Comment: Thanks Ian! I guess I should of thought about using borders... Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

But this is just for a hover effect, if you want a transition, then the above answer should work.